# Latex citeA - error <argument> ...ter \NAT@ifcmd \NAT@tmp (@)(@)\@nil

Tags: bibtex, citing, apacite

I'm using a template from AGU journals.

I've been using \cite and \citep to cite my references using .bib file. I had no problem with it. But as I was about to submit I saw that I do not suppose to use \citep and use instead \citeA. But when I've made this change I get errors:

**! Undefined control sequence.**

**...ter \NAT@ifcmd \NAT@tmp (@)(@)@nil**

How can I correct this?

Hope someone can help me with this

Comment: Unfortunately, errors like this are extremely hard to diagnose without code that reproduces them. Is there any chance you could show us a small example document that we can run on our machines (so with all references to external files we don't have removed) and that reproduces the issue (a so-called MWE: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)?

Comment: If you are loading `apacite` with the `natbibapa` option (which I assume you are), then you can't use the `apacite` citation commands like `\citeA`. You have to use one or the other.  See [How to write "(e.g. Surname, 2018)" with apacite?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/408564) for some discussion of the differences.